# Angular 2(or ionic 2) how to import vis

Tags: angular, import, ionic2, vis.js

I just try

```
npm install vis --save

import * as Vis from 'vis';
```

but it occurred that

> TypeError : hammer.assign is not a function

I searched online but only found a similar question

https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/2000

It said that materialize.js and vis.js, include hammer.js. So just import vis.js before materialize.js.

So how can I import vis.js before the file include hammer.js ?

Or if not the reason, then how to solve the error?

vis@4.20.1

hammerjs@2.0.8

cordova 6.5.0

ionic 2.1.17

Thanks in advance, I am new to angular 2 and ionic 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check in your `node_modules` if `hammerjs` is really installed?

- If it is the case, can you add `import 'hammerjs';` in your app's root module and try again?
- Otherwise, can you install it and try again (`npm install --save hammerjs`)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But it doesn't work neither.I just found there are two hammer.js in node_modules. One in /hammerjs ,the other in vis/lib/module.

Comment: Hey, so silly am I.You are right,but it doesn't work in app's root module but in the used component (in my app is home.ts).Thanks again.

Comment: Glad this helped ;) !

Answer (score 0):

I once ran into this kind of error, but not with those modules. (So I don't know if it'll work for you)

It might happen because `hammerjs` overrides `visjs`'s `hammerjs`. Since they probably do not use exact same versions, it can throw errors...

If `vis.js` includes `hammer.js` you don't need to import `hammer.js`, so uninstall it by deleting it from `node_modules` and `package.json` (`npm uninstall hammerjs --save`). Then re run `npm i`

You should try to `rm -rf node_modules` and then `npm i` again if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help.I am sad that it doesn't work.And I found that there are six hammer.js in node_modules.And the hammer.js in vis/lib/module, have the following code : require('hammerjs').

Answer (score 0):

For Whoever get stuck in this.

Make sure you initialize your data , edges and nodes in ionViewDidLoad() else you will get an error